# How to sort Django database using Javascript and display it on a website

Tags: javascript, django-database

Problem: I need to order a set of problems on my website by difficulty when someone clicks on the 'sort: difficulty' button.

How do I sort the problems by difficulty by easiest (starting from 0) to hardest?

I have a database with the model

```
class Problemspage(models.Model):
    problemname = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    difficultyproblem = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

With the name of the problem, and the difficulty of the problem.

I have managed to sort my problems alphabetically but my javascript sorts the displayed li tags.

I don't know how to sort the problem difficulty but only display the problem name relative to the order of the difficulty number.

```
        function sortListDir() {
            var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
            list = document.getElementById("id01");
            switching = true;
            dir = "asc";
            while (switching) {
                switching = false;
                b = list.getElementsByTagName("LI");
                for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
                    shouldSwitch = false;

                    if (dir == "asc") {
                        if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                            shouldSwitch= true;
                            break;
                        }
                    } else if (dir == "desc") {
                        if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() < b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                            shouldSwitch= true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (shouldSwitch) {
                    b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
                    switching = true;
                    switchcount ++;
                } else {
                    if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                        dir = "desc";
                        switching = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```